# django.views / django.models, can't delete entities with foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Actually I have two things that don't seem to work. I'll list couple of models and their dependencies (shortened). The StudentGroup has students (which may be active/inactive), and messages, which are listed as chat.

In views.py, when I call delete_group(), I want to make all students inactive and delete all of the messages relevant to the group.

```
class StudentsGroup(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User,limit_choices_to={'is_staff': False}, related_name="user_groups",blank=True)
    finished = models.ManyToManyField(User,limit_choices_to={'is_staff': False}, related_name="finished_user_groups",blank=True)


class Message(models.Model):
    group=models.ForeignKey(StudentsGroup)


def delete_group(request,group):

    Message.objects.filter(group=group).delete()
    groupl=StudentsGroup.objects.get(id=group)
    for s in group1.students.all():
        groupl.finished.add(s)
        group1.save()
```

Nothing changes. I've tried similar things in console and it seemed to be ok. Tried bunch of similar code. 
Tried to add makemigrations to the server restarting but still no result. 
Kinda noob in django and webdev overall, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your `delete_group` function, what is the value of `group1.students.all()`?

Answer (score 0):

In your line

```
Message.objects.filter(group=group).delete()
```

it looks like you haven't yet converted `group` from the raw ID value to an actual StudentGroup instance. If `group` is supplied to the function as a StudentGroup instance, then this should work. If, as I suspect, `group` is just a raw ID value, then your filter queries should be:

```
Message.objects.filter(group_id=group).delete()
```

It's nicer however to work with objects rather than IDs. Try instead doing this:

```
group = StudentGroup.objects.get(id=group)
Message.objects.filter(group=group).delete()
```

Then you can do other things like `group = get_object_or_404(StudentGroup, id=group)`.

As for the second part, moving the Students to the group's `finished` list, your code looks reasonable, though you don't need the `.save()` part. I suspect the errors may be due to the object not being correctly instantiated yet, as with above.

However you should be able to do all this in a single line in Django 1.9+, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add

```
group1.finished.add(*list(group1.students.all()))
```